# Newly brought Apple Pencil(1st generation) didn’t connect with my iPad (8th generation) when I plugged it

Tags: ipad, bluetooth, ipados, apple-pencil

In this year I brought an iPad (8th generation). And newly brought Apple Pencil (1st generation) I tried to connect with plugging it to the IPad. Sometimes the pop up  came up and disappeared. When I tap the “pair” button it shows on the Bluetooth settings shows `Connected`, after 2 seconds it shows `Not connected`. I tried new another two Apple Pencils with the iPad but it didn’t work either.
I tried all the troubleshooting methods with this problem. And I upgraded the `IPad OS` to Latest `IPad OS 15.0.2` but didn’t work.

[image]

Sometimes Apple Pencil shows on the `Other Devices`  when I tapped on it the error message popped-up.

Comment: You can test what’s on this [page](https://support.apple.com/en-sg/HT205236). It give some try in case of pairing problems

Comment: I tried all the instructions on that site. But didn’t work

Comment: Saying you tried "all the troubleshooting methods" doesn't really help as we have no idea what you did.  Did you plug the Pencil into the iPad's lightning port first?  The Pencil will not be displayed in Bluetooth until it's connected via the lightning port.

Comment: when all the times I pugged the Apple Pencil into the iPad connecting pop-up came can disappear. When I tapped the pair button before it disappears pencil connect to the iPad and shows “Not Connected” in Bluetooth settings. After seen a problem like this I downloaded “Wunderfind”. My Apple Pencil shows on it can finally now connecting can disconnecting like a loop. Each time pencil connected to iPad, pencil’s battery increases from 3% to 100%. I will send my screen recording on my Onedrive. I will put the link down below⬇️. [link](https://1drv.ms/v/s!Ao_9vqgypQmEhkiGMonckyk9VS-f) ‘problem’